# how can we get the xml vector image file from server & view it in the imageview in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

how to change this xml file to view as a image in android studio which path is from server , it should not change to png, it should view with xml .how it is possible. Please help me

**I tried like this but it is not working**

String uri = "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/android.image/success.xml";

```
VectorDrawable d = new VectorDrawable();
    try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream(uri))
    {
        XmlPullParser p = Xml.newPullParser();
        p.setInput( in, null );
        d.inflate( c.getResources(), p, Xml.asAttributeSet(p) ); // FAILS
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
    Drawable res;
    if(imageResource!=0){
        res = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    }
    else{
        res = c.getResources().getDrawable(c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName()));
    }
```

Thanks & regards

Comment: a vector file which comes from server

Answer (score 0):

Treat this xml as file when downloading from server. Well i m not sure of this. but you can try this

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead